# Jquery : ajax request -> jquery plugin's don't work anymore

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use a Jquery plugin to display tooltip on a tag, but now I added ajax request to my website. So, when I request new links (via ajax), the tooltip plugin doesn't work on those links.
I understand that the due of the plugin is :

```
//Select all anchor tag with rel set to tooltip
$('a[rel=tooltip]').mouseover(function(e) 


 ...
```

Is there a solution to reload the javascript, so my  will have mouseover functions? Something to add in the ajax request ?
Thanks.

EDIT : Here's my [script](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1a22).

Comment: You need to quote the attribute value: `$('a[rel="tooltip"]')`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `.live()` in jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).  This will bind to events for elements present in the DOM at the time of execution as well as those added throughout the life of the document.

Comment: @eouti: Then go learn about it.  @David has provided a link to the documentation.

Comment: @eouti: Where you normally call `.mouseover(function())` on a jQuery object, you'd instead call `.live('mouseover', function())` to bind the event.  The difference is that it will bind to elements which are added to the DOM later.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks dude. But it partially works, tooltip appears, but it stays long time, no fade (some bugs in fact). Another solution ?

Comment: @eouti: Your only options are to use `.live` (and potentially debug whatever problems you're having) or to re-bind any time the DOM changes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run over your DOM again, using the same initialisation code that the plugin documentation suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.delegate()` or `.live()` methods (delegate is a little bit better) to bind the event on your object.

check this link, it will explain you difference between live ans delegate.

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

New DOM object reference by your pattern must raise event.

Rgds

Comment: I've posted my script for more comprehension

Comment: @eouti check your [script](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1a23) that I modified.
I make it whith .live() method.

Comment: @eouti may be I had made a syntax fault. Do you have any error?